# Visual Studio 2022 builds Qt5 application in debug configuration but not in release configuration

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I just realized that after upgrading to Visual Studio 2022 (with Qt 5.15.2_msvc2019_64) my application doesn't work in release configuration anymore.

First I get an error message saying "This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem." and then I get a 'No Symbols Loaded' tab that says "Qt5Core.pdb not loaded" with Module Information saying that the Original Location is my MikTex path!?

Is this related? Where can the path to the pdbs and dlls be set?
Any hints on where I went wrong during installation?

EDIT: The application depends on the Qt modules core, gui, widgets, network, printsupport and serialport. Inspecting the debug output, I found out that Qt5Network.dll and Qt5SerialPort.dll are loaded from C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin, which is what I would expect. However, the rest of the Qt modules is loaded from C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\MikTeX\miktex\bin\x64. So something is telling Visual Studio to load it from there, I suppose because the dlls have been registered from there when I installed Visual Studio 2022. Any ideas how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to the the latest VS (17.3.1) the project now builds in release configuration as well.
However, I doubt this is a bug in 17.2 but rather a bug in the install process itself.